# Though the variable is defined am getting a error

Tags: php, mongodb

I have define the storedUsername and storedPassword , but am still facing the error stating that

> Notice: Undefined variable: storedUsername in C:\xampp\htdocs\mongosample\index.php on line 13

```
<?php
include './connect.php';
if(($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST") && (!empty($_POST['username'])) && (!empty($_POST['password']))){
$postedUsername = $_POST['username'];
$postedPassword = $_POST['password'];
    $userDatabaseFind = $database->Bcard->find(array('username' => $postedUsername, 'password' => $postedPassword));

    foreach ($userDatabaseFind as $useFind){
        $storedUsername = $useFind['username'];
        $storedPassword = $useFind['password'];
    }

    if(($postedUsername == $storedUsername) && ($postedPassword == $storedPassword)){
        header('location:welcome.php');
    }
    else{
        echo 'Error';
    }
}   ?>
```

I do , know that password should not passed in blank texts,so please don't mention

Comment: try **print_r($userDatabaseFind);** are you getting any records ?

Comment: it's probably not getting that variable. Have you tried print_r($$userDatabaseFind) first? Check if the username is retrieved from the database. Then, after the loop, var_dump($storedUsername);

Comment: i have also noticed you have used for loop .. why so ? if you are supposed to get only 1 record, use limit in your query and exclude forloop from your code ..

Comment: Perhaps you have no results to loop through.  And hence $storedUsername and $storedPassword never get defined.  Leading to an undefined variable in the following conditional (the block containing the header line).

Answer (score -1):

You should initialize your variable before foreach loop

```
$storedUsername = '';
$storedPassword = '';
```

then comes your foreach loop

Comment: Y MY ANSWER IS DOWNVOTED ?

Comment: AbuHuraira - perhaps if you include some context, some explanation of why and how this change will provide a solution, your answer will be clearer for people to understand.